# HTTPS vs HTTP caching Javascript file?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

I am developing on a server which was initially running HTTP protocol. After switching to HTTPS protocol, any changes done on the Javascript file won't update any longer. I've made sure that, the file was in fact saved properly, upload and re-downloaded the file to make sure the changes on the code were really there and, it was.

Here is my question, why https won't react to changes I made to the file but, as soon as I use http, the changes are displayed?

Comment: Image: http://intersofts.com/sample.png

Answer (score 1):

Your Javascipt source code appear to attempt to POST to an HTTP URL when you are using HTTPS. Most modern browsers block this as this is insecure. If your POST URL supports HTTPS, change it and you should see this work.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. If you look at the image, you will see that, the old code was written statically while, the change I've made makes the protocol and domain dynamic (https/http). I just can't figure out why my code changes doesn't take effect on https while it does when I load the page using http.